# Apache Velocity (VTL) Performance Profiling

Tags: profiling, velocity

I need to figure out how long some code is taking in Velocity (VTL). Something like this:

```
#set(start = getTickCount())

... do some stuff that takes a while ...

#set(end = getTickCount()) 

#set(time = end - start) 

It took $time milliseconds!
```

Does Velocity have a getTickCount() function or some equivalent? Or is there some other recommended way to do profiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my stock VelocityTools is a logging profiler, but if you want to do it more manually as you indicate, you could just stick a tool in there that gives you the `currentTimeMillis`, or add the `System` class directly as per the [static classes docs](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html#supportforstaticclasses).